# what "ranging" means in "He was a veteran of a hundred rangings"?

Tags: meaning

This sentence is picked from "A Song of Ice & Fire:A Game of Thrones". I have no idea of the phrase"a hundred rangings". I'm not a native English speaker. I appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As medica said in a (now deleted) comment, "He" is a ranger. In the series, Rangers go on forays beyond the wall, into the wild lands to suppress the people who live there. Each foray is called a "ranging".

Many works of fiction employ invented vocabularies as part of the fictitious world invented by the author.